# Parsing single decimal hour in Pandas using Windows

Tags: python, pandas, strftime

I've got the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
date         hour  
20140101     0 
20140101     1 
20140101     2  
20140101     3   
20140101     4
...          ...
```

I want to combine these two to a datetime column. I've tried the following, but I get an error because I'm using Windows, I think:

```
wdf['date'] = wdf['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + wdf['hour'].astype(str)
wdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(wdf['date'], format='%Y%m%d %-H')
```

> **ValueError**: '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y%m%d %-H'

I've tried `%#H`, but that resulted in a similar error. I have to use the dash or pound sign, because the hour notation is a single decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using [`zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to pad with `0` where needed, and use the regular `%H`.

try this:

```py
wdf['date'] = wdf['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + wdf['hour'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
wdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(wdf['date'], format='%Y%m%d %H')
```

Output:

```
                 date  hour
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00     0
1 2014-01-01 01:00:00     1
2 2014-01-01 02:00:00     2
3 2014-01-01 03:00:00     3
4 2014-01-01 04:00:00     4
```